# How to get the number of messages for Akka Actor?

Tags: java, akka, metrics

I need to get a metric for each actor. I watched Kamon but did not find such functionality. How can I get count messages passing through the actor?

Comment: Please share the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
(this.mailbos() as BoundedDequeBasedMailbox.MessageQueue).size()
```